# Get multi-part form non-file items in Filter without ruining the request for servlet

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, multipart

Is there anyway to get the items from a multipart form in a Filter while still leaving the request alone so that I can still use the Apache FileUpload in the servlet to process the request?

Comment: It's possible, but very clumsy. What's the functional requirement? Why not just parse it once in filter using Commons FileUpload and change the servlet to retrieve the already-parsed items? A bit the idea of [this `MultipartFilter`](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/11/multipartfilter.html) for example.

Comment: We already have a lot of servlets set up that use FileUpload and so I'd rather fix the Filter instead of the numerous servlets if possible.

Comment: Well, start with `HttpServletRequestWrapper` wherein you copy the request body and provide it instead. The copy can then be used for filter's purposes as well. This is only potentially going to be memory hogging if you allow/expect large file uploads. You'd probably want to look at temp disk solutions. I'd really prefer parsing it once and changing all multipart/form-data servlets. It won't require more time I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the idea - I'll try it though I'd prefer not to make a copy of the body for the exact reason you mention - memory.

Comment: There is no other way. It can be read only once. The client ain't going to resend it once again.